# Selecting the three youngest players in a database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm currently learning SQL(postgresql) at school but I'm having a hard time understanding something that looks like a simple query. 
The excercise was to get the three youngest players in a database without using `FETCH` or `LIMIT`. This is the answer to the problem:

```
SELECT playerid, name, birth_date
FROM players p1
WHERE 2>=
      (SELECT count(*)
       FROM players p2
       WHERE p2.birth_date > p1.birth_date);
```

This works fine but all I want to know is why does this return the 3 youngest players?

Comment: The inner query counts how many players (p2) are older than the current player (p1).  The initial query says to list all those players who have 2 or less players older than them.  The youngest player has no players older than them, the second youngest has 1, and the third youngest, 2.  Those 3 players are thus the only ones returned.

Comment: Thank you very much @JohnLBevan for your answer, exactly the explanation I was looking for! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number() window function:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT playerid, name, birth_date, row_number() over (order by birth_date) rn
  FROM players p1 
) a WHERE rn <= 3
```

Comment: I was not asking if there were better alternatives but to explain how the query in my post worked

Answer (score 1):

The sub query on where clause returns the number of players which birth_date is greater than the row returned by the main query. So the 2 >= (sub query) filters only the records which there are only 2 or less younger players.

You can put the sub query on the select clause to get what it returns.

```
SELECT playerid, name, birth_date,     (SELECT count(*)
   FROM players p2
   WHERE p2.birth_date > p1.birth_date) youngers_count
FROM players p1
WHERE 2>=
  (SELECT count(*)
   FROM players p2
   WHERE p2.birth_date > p1.birth_date);
```